# Is it possible to add new contacts and imported contacts to an already active Journey in Journey Builder with set data entry?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

Right now, my entry criteria is to use any contacts that have signed up using a form on our website. I was wondering if it is possible in Marketing Cloud to either add newly created contacts or contacts from an imported list to this active Journey? I want these new contacts to follow the same journey as the ones who signed up on the website. Would I need to edit the existing data entry criteria or clone that journey and add the contacts in that way?

Comment: Is it a one time load or would you need to be able to add them to the journey on a regular basis? It might be easier to just create a copy of your existing journey and create it with a Data Extension entry source and put all your new contacts into that DE.

Comment: It would not be a one time load. It would be an ongoing load of about 100 contacts or more at a time. Like once a week, once a month, etc. Can you create a Data Extension entry based on ongoing imported contacts?

Comment: You would have to copy the whole journey and replace the entry source in that copy with a Data Extension. Then use that DE to load new contacts. You would basically have two separate journeys that do exactly the same thing but get fed with data in two different ways.

Comment: Thanks! It's possible to create a data extension entry where I can add imported leads, correct? This can be done multiple times or is it a one-time load?

Comment: Both are possible with a Data Extension